# Using basename inside for each gnu Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am wondering how to use `basename` inside for each? I think maybe the reason basename does not work is that each "$file" is actually a path to a file, not simply a filename.

```
DOCKER_TAG=foobar
DOCKER_RUN=docker run -v `pwd`:/root -it --rm -w /root ${DOCKER_TAG}
TEST_DIR=test_cases

dockerbuild: App/App.csproj
    docker build . -t ${DOCKER_TAG}

%.run: %.txt dockerbuild 
    ${DOCKER_RUN} $<

%.out: %.txt dockerbuild
    ${DOCKER_RUN} $< > $@

%.test: %.out
    python3 evaluate.py $<

.PHONY: regression
regression: $(TEST_DIR)/*.txt
    for file in $^ ; do \
        echo $(basename $${file}).test ; \
    done
```

Returns (I expected `.txt` to have been replaced with `.test`)

```
test_cases/00_example.txt.test
test_cases/01_simplest_possible.txt.test
test_cases/02_two_users.txt.test
test_cases/03_five_users.txt.test
test_cases/04_one_interferer.txt.test
test_cases/05_equatorial_plane.txt.test
test_cases/06_partially_fullfillable.txt.test
test_cases/07_eighteen_planes.txt.test
test_cases/08_eighteen_planes_northern.txt.test
test_cases/09_ten_thousand_users.txt.test
test_cases/10_ten_thousand_users_geo_belt.txt.test
test_cases/11_one_hundred_thousand_users.txt.test
test_cases/test.txt.test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(basename)` function is evaluated by `make` *before* the shell runs the loop. So you are effectively running

```
for file in /path/to/moo.txt /path/to/bar.txt /path/to/baz.txt; do
    echo ${file}.test ;
done
```

The shell's `basename` command also removes the path, but you might want to fix this with something like

```
.PHONY: regression
regression: $(TEST_DIR)/*.txt
    printf '%s\n' $^ | sed 's/\.txt$$/.test/'
```

though of course, a better solution is to use `make` functions instead.

```
.PHONY: regression
regression: $(TEST_DIR)/*.txt
    printf '%s\n' $(patsubst %,%.test,$(basename $^))
```

If you want to do something more than just print the file names, a more idiomatic solution is to create a pattern rule and run it on each of the input files.

```
.PHONY: regression
regression: $(patsubst %.txt,%.test,$(wildcard $(TEST_DIR)/%.txt))

$(TEST_DIR)/%.test: $(TEST_DIR)/%.txt
    printf '%s\n' $@ # or whatever you really wanted to do
```